# Cumulative list of a column using groupby

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

Hi so I have the following dataframe:

```
   Fruit  metric
0  Apple     NaN
1  Apple   100.0
2  Apple     NaN
3  Peach    70.0
4   Pear   120.0
5   Pear   100.0
6   Pear     NaN
```

My objective is to groupby fruit and in order, add each value of `metric` that is not null to a cumulative list with its own separate column like so:

```
   Fruit  metric  metric_cum
0  Apple     NaN          []
1  Apple   100.0       [100]
2  Apple     NaN       [100]
3  Peach    70.0        [70]
4   Pear   120.0       [120]
5   Pear   100.0  [120, 100]
6   Pear     NaN  [120, 100]
```

I have tried doing this:

```
df['metric1'] = df['metric'].astype(str)
df.groupby('Fruit')['metric1'].cumsum()
```

But this results in a `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`.

I have also tried doing this:

```
df.groupby('Fruit')['metric'].apply(list)
```

Resulting in:

```
Fruit
Apple      [nan, 100.0, nan]
Peach                 [70.0]
Pear     [120.0, 100.0, nan]
Name: metric, dtype: object
```

But this is not cumulative and isn't able to made into a column.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
df['metric'] = df['metric'].apply(lambda x: [] if pd.isnull(x) else [int(x)])
df['metric_cum'] = df.groupby('Fruit')['metric'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
print (df)
   Fruit metric  metric_cum
0  Apple     []          []
1  Apple  [100]       [100]
2  Apple     []       [100]
3  Peach   [70]        [70]
4   Pear  [120]       [120]
5   Pear  [100]  [120, 100]
6   Pear     []  [120, 100]
```

Or:

```
a = df['metric'].apply(lambda x: [] if pd.isnull(x) else [int(x)])
df['metric_cum'] = a.groupby(df['Fruit']).apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
print (df)
   Fruit  metric  metric_cum
0  Apple     NaN          []
1  Apple   100.0       [100]
2  Apple     NaN       [100]
3  Peach    70.0        [70]
4   Pear   120.0       [120]
5   Pear   100.0  [120, 100]
6   Pear     NaN  [120, 100]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
f = lambda x: pd.Series(x).dropna().astype(int).tolist()
c = pd.Series.cumsum
df.assign(metric_cum=df.metric.apply(f).groupby(df.Fruit).apply(c))

   Fruit  metric  metric_cum
0  Apple     NaN          []
1  Apple   100.0       [100]
2  Apple     NaN       [100]
3  Peach    70.0        [70]
4   Pear   120.0       [120]
5   Pear   100.0  [120, 100]
6   Pear     NaN  [120, 100]
```